# How to push element in array in AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to update array in Firebase db. Here is the Firebase user collection.
I am trying to create a group and updating id in users/groups collection.

```
"users" : {
    "F0m0l0JhIXMhlQmEMv5ci1MapLM2" : {
      "address" : "Address 123334",
      "displayName" : "Prashant 1",
      "email" : "fireapps@gmail.com",
      "groups" : [ "-KbzjEnTCGAto8SQbvzc", "-KbzjCLP3Aw2jfa0NmHO" ],
      "name" : "Prashant",
      "phone" : "9900XXXX190"
    }
  }
```

I want to add new key in `groups` array using AngularFire2. How to update the array?

Comment: This array needs to parse before adding anything to the signature.

Comment: you mean first copy to local array and add new element and push to Groups?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using angularefire2, so update `groups` node would be

```
...
constructor(
  private af: AngularFire,
  ) {}
...
this.af.database.object('/users/F0m0l0JhIXMhlQmEMv5ci1MapLM2').update({
    "groups": "your new key" // <--------
  })
  .catch (error =>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

If you want to use your own keys then:

```
this.af.database.object('/users/F0m0l0JhIXMhlQmEMv5ci1MapLM2/groups').update({
  "0": "group 1 key",
  "1": "group 2 key",
  "custom key": "group x key"
}).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

If you have your data in an array named `updateArray`, then update `groups` node with such array. Something likes

```
this.af.database.object('/users/F0m0l0JhIXMhlQmEMv5ci1MapLM2/groups').update(updateArray).catch(error =>{ console.log(error); });
```

Comment: this will update as "groups" : "new key" in firebase. I want to add it in group array like.
"groups" : 0:" group 1 key ",
1 : "group 2 key ",
2: "group 3 key"

Comment: @user3440700 See my added options for custom keys.

Comment: could you use the same flow to remove a value from an array?